# Add .NET dll's at runtime or a less error-prone alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Another one of those "Best way to X" but I have a question about how I should go about designing this certain piece of software I am working on.

I have this C# WPF software (lets call it ENGINE) that iterates over a list of TASKS and calls the same three methods on each TASK: initialize(), calculate(), and save().

```
//Simplified obviously (I use indexes vs. foreach because of other code I left out)
while(currentOperatingIndex < tasks.Count)
{
    Task currentTask = tasks.ElementAt(currentOperatingIndex);
    currentTask.initialize();
    currentTask.calculate();
    currentTask.save();
    currentOperatingIndex++;
}
```

Now these TASKS I need to load dynamically into the ENGINE program at runtime. The engine program will never be re-built or chang when a new TASK is created. So I designed it such that each TASK will be in its own library DLL. Thus, the engine will iterate a folder of DLL files at runtime and load in each DLL into the assembly.

I designed it like this because each TASK initializes, calculates and saves differently. For example, say I want to add a new task, I dont have to change the ENGINE's code, or any other DLL, I just create a new DLL for the TASK, make sure it has those 3 functions, and put it in the folder. My goal is that when a new TASK is needed a programmer can open up visual studio, create a new C# library, create three functions, and write the implementation.

Is this the best way to handle a 'plugin-like' functionality?

Hopefully I am clear.

Comment: Is it for educational purposes or you actually need to do something like this ([MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) may be an option if you just need to use it).

Comment: It's a personal project I am working on. Looking into MEF.

Comment: use MEF, although its a little overkill for what u need. I usually end up writing my own. Enumerate all *.dll in a directory, do a load assembly on each , iterate over the types and find those that implement your interface

Comment: @pm100 Thanks for the info. As for loading the DLL's is it possible to load them into the assembly and keep a reference on it so when I call *.calculate(); I can go loadedDllExample.calculate();. Or how does that work?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you should write an answer stating to use MEF because I will flag it as the answer. It's a great way to design plugins.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer (perfectly ok to do so) as I don't want to write complete answer :). Note that approach in @KenanKocaerkek answer is perfectly valid one (and more or less base of most more elaborate solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Alexei Levenkov in a comment to my question if you are looking to dynamically add plugins to a program without adding extra code to include them, use MEF where it imports many plugins into a catalog and you can use it from there. Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface (for example ICalcTask) has three methods: initialize, calculate, save.

Write plugin class library dlls including classes implemeting ICalcTask interface.

Let your host application scans dlls containing ICalcTask implementations in plugins directory.

Comment: That's exactly what I am currently doing. I'm just curious if adding DLL's at runtime is not bad-code and if there is a better way to do this. Where would the Interface be declared?

Comment: I think it's not bad. For example define interface in "TaskApp.Common.DLL". Host app project and plugin library projects references "TaskApp.Common.DLL".